# Minimum palindrome count in string

Tags: c++, algorithm

Can someone help me with a solution for finding the minimum count of palindromes in which the given string can be split into?
example:

```
abcdef = 6 //the palindromes are (a,b,c,d,e,f)
bbbaxx = 3 //(bbb, a, xx)
level = 1 // (level)
```

Comment: @aix: The minimum number of partitions, such that each substring is a palindrome, is how I read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using recursion with dynamic programming

if the string is a palindrome then result is one,
otherwise you split your string in 2 (have to do it foe every pair) and return the mininimum sum of the two call of minPalinCount on each part.

in pseudo code you have something like this

```
minPalinCount(s)
    s is a palindrome ?
       return 1
    else
        for each position in s
           s1,s2 = s split in 2 at this position
           count = min(minPalinCount(s1) + minPalinCount(s2), count)
        return count
```

in c++

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


bool ispalind(string s1)
{
    int s1i = 0;
    while (s1i < s1.size())
    {
        if (s1[s1i] != s1[s1.size() - 1 - s1i ])
            return false;
        s1i++;
    }
    return true;
}

int palindromeCount(string a)
{
    if (ispalind(a))
        return 1;
    else
    {
        int min = a.size();
        for (int i = 1; i < a.size() ; i++)
            min = std::min(palindromeCount(a.substr(0, i)) + palindromeCount(a.substr(i, a.size() - i)), min);
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will be too slow. There will be lots of re-computing.

Comment: What's the running time of this? Also, I suppose you can cache the previously computed solutions to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head i can think of a dynamic programming solution.
M[i,j]--> denotes the palindrome beginning at i and ending at j... it is true if such a palindrome exists false otherwise
M[i,j] = true iff M[i+1,j-1] == true && Str[i]==str[j]
storing this stuff in an appropriate data structure keyed by the end index , we can traverse this structure backwards from the palindrome ending at 'n' followed by palindrome ending at the index where the palindrome begun for the previous palindrome ending at n and so on.

O(n^2). not sure if there is a greedy divide-conquer algo that does better,